# Is there a "de-completion" for complete local rings?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a complete local ring. Is there a local ring $A_0$ and a local homomorphism $i:A_0\to A$ inducing an isomorphism after completion and satisfying the following universal property?

For any local homomorphism $h:B\to A$ which is an isomorphism after completion there exists a local homomorphism $f:A_0\to B$ such that $hf=i$.

If not, any similar variant will be welcomed (for instance $A$ noetherian and a universal property only for noetherian rings, the equicharacteristic case, the case of perfect residue field, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}=(\Bbb{Z}-(p))^{-1}\Bbb{Z}$ is the unique smallest local domain whose completion is $\Bbb{Z}_p$. Your question is if such a unique smallest local domain exists for all complete local domain. The answer is no, $\Bbb{Q}[[t]]$ has many different smallest local domains, try with $\Bbb{Q}[t]_{(t)}$ and $\Bbb{Q}[f]_{(f)}$ where $f=\sum_{k=1}^\infty t^{k!}$.

The intersection of $(\Bbb{Q}[t]-(t))^{-1}\Bbb{Q}[t]$ and $(\Bbb{Q}[f]-(f))^{-1}\Bbb{Q}[f]$ is $\Bbb{Q}$. However they are isomorphic.

For a non-isomorphic example you can look at the completion of $\bigcup_{p\ \nmid\ n} \Bbb{Z}_p[\zeta_n]$ which is $R=\{ \sum_{j\ge 0} a_j p^j, a_j \in \{\zeta_n,p\nmid n\} \cup 0\}$.

With $R_1=\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}[\bigcup_{p\ \nmid\ n} \zeta_n]$ then $(R_1)_{R_1\cap p R}$ is a smallest local domain algebraic over $\Bbb{Z}$ whereas with $R_2=\Bbb{Z}[\{ \sum_{j\ge 0} \zeta_{2^j n} p^j\}]$ then $(R_2)_{(p)}\cap \overline{\Bbb{Z}_p}=\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}$.

Comment: Thank you for the examples.